# Google play androidpublisher error with mime types

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I try to upoload apk file via android publisher to Google play, but function upload still returns me error with mimeType, but i think that i have mimeType set correctly.

> Media type \'application/json\' is not supported. Valid media types:
>   [application/octet-stream, application/vnd.android.package-archive]'

I think that mimeType is set correctly, somebody solved the same error?

my code:

```
var google = require('googleapis').google;

var play = google.androidpublisher({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: oauth2Client,
        params: {
            packageName: APP_ID
        }
});

play.edits.apks.upload({
                editId: edit.id,
                packageName: APP_ID,
                media: {
                    mimeType: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
                    body: apk,
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggled with this for a while, I tried to get file content by `fs.readFileSync()`. But it turned out `upload` simply cannot handle `Buffer`, so the below change did the trick:

```
edits.apks.upload({
    auth: authClient,
    editId: editResource.id,
    packageName,
    media: {
        mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
        body: fs.createReadStream(pathToApk),
    },
})
```